# R-style point background in gnuplot

Tags: r, gnuplot

I've recently switched from R to gnuplot for plotting my graphs in my lab reports. I have grown very accustomed to the way that R makes points like black rings with white backgrounds:

```
points(x, y, pch=21, bg="white")
```

Is there any way to reproduce the same effect with gnuplot? I have used the following up until now, but the disadvantage of this method is that the points "merge" together when they're too close.

```
plot 'mypoints.dat' w p pt 7 ps 2 lc rgb 'black', \
     'mypoints.dat' w p pt 7 ps 1.9 lc rgb 'white'
```

The point-type 6 doesn't help here, since the points don't write over each other but through.

I would be very grateful for a solution to my problem.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `circles` plotting style to draw filled circles:

```
set style circle radius char 1
plot 'mypoints.dat' with circles fc rgb 'white' fs solid border lc rgb 'black'
```

The value following `radius` can be given in different 'units' (`first`, `second`, `graph`, `screen`, or `character`, see `help coordinates`). Using `char` allows you to specify the radius independently of the axis scales. Alternatively you could give a third, constant value in the `using` statement. This is then given in `first` units, i.e. uses the scaling of the x-axis: `plot 'mypoints.dat' using 1:2:(0.1) with circles ...`.

To illustrate this, consider the following script

```
set samples 100
set style circle radius char 1
set xrange[0:1]
plot '+' using (rand(0)):(rand(0)) with circles fc rgb 'white' fs solid border lc rgb 'black'
```

with the result (with 4.6.4):

[image]

Comment: I don't get the "radius char 1" part, and I can't seem to find an explanation for that... But I can get my points to look nice, thank you for the nice working example! :)

Comment: Thank you, that clarified things for me. I will upvote as soon as I have the necessary reputation ;-)

Comment: I thought you can always upvote on answers to your own questions... I never asked a question here :)